# CardView images in recycler zoomed in too much on scroll on tablet

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I have a fragment that contains cards when the user executes a search. The cards contain 3 images and text. No problems on phone. The first handful of cards look fine on tablet until the user scrolls. The newly loaded cards have images that are zoomed in way to much. Since there's no problems until scrolling I know this must have something to do with my binding

```
    public void bind(Model model) {
        mModel = model;
        Glide.with(mCtx).load(model.getImage1()).into(imageView1);
        Glide.with(mCtx).load(model.getImage2()).into(imageView2);
        Glide.with(mCtx).load(model.getImage3()).into(imageView3);

        textViewFirstName.setText(model.getFirstName());
        textViewLastName.setText(model.getLastName());
    }
```

However I'm confused because the images look just fine on phone after scroll. Please help

Answer (score 0):

solved just use the Picasso library instead of the garbage Glide library